# Android - Layout Weight fills the whole Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have problem with an android layout. For an AlerDialog I've built a custom view:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/new_game"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/random"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players2"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players4"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players6"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players8"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/friends"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players2"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players4"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players6"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/players8"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/more"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<Button
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/computer"
    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text" />
```

Unfortunately the TableLayout results in a Dialog, which fills the whole screen. So there is unused space I don't want. Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unc9g.png

Do you have an idea what I need to change to get unused space away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your top layout's `layout_height` to `wrap_content`
Also try this:

```
dlg.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

With `dlg` is your dialog before show.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your top level layout is not using **match_parent** or **fill_parent** as it's height. Also you may want to set the gravity of the top level layout to "**center**" or "**center_vertical**" to center the layout and make it look much cleaner.